# Is the derivative of a Lebesgue integral equal to the original function being integrated almost everywhere?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

In this question, I am specifically interested in the following case:

Let *f*:R->R be a Borel-measurable function from the reals to the reals and let

$g(x)\ =\ \int_{b}^x\ f(t)\ dt$,

where the integral is the Lebesgue integral and b is a real constant.  I would presume

$g'(x) = f(x) $ a. e.

Is this true?  Is there a published reference for this?  (It might be an exercise in a book.)  I tried looking in Rao's encyclopedic compendium on Lebesgue measure and integration, among others, but couldn't seem to find an answer.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the riemann and lebesgue integral are the same on riemann integrable functions. You would only have to check for $L^1$-limits of Riemann integrable functions.

Comment: Look up Lebesgue differentiation theorem